# Image upload using typescript in mobile form data return none

Tags: android, ios, typescript, mobile, nativescript

I am new to typescript and trying to upload an image from my mobile SD card. I am getting the image path when browsing the image. And when I pass this along with the form data None is returning. It would be great if someone give a helping hand to figure out the issue.

I am using "nativescript-imagepicker" library for getting image from SD Card..

```
sendPicture(uri: string, modelContext: any){
  let _formData = new FormData();
  _formData.append("profile_image", uri);
  let body = _formData;
  updateAvatarService(this.userToken,body).subscribe(data => {
  });
}

updateAvatarService(token,body): Observable<any> { 
            return this.httpClass.patchMethodWithToken(URL,token,body)
            .map(response => {
             return response;
           }) 
    }

patchMethodWithToken(url: string, token: string,  data: Object ) {
    let headers = new Headers();
   headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    headers.append('Authorization', "Token " + token);
    headers.append('Content-Disposition', "form-data");    
        let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
    if (this.checkNetworkConnection()) {
      return this.http
        .patch(url, JSON.stringify(data), options)
        .map(response => {
          return response.json();
        })
        .catch(this.handleErrors);
    }
  }
```

Comment: Provide more info with code

Comment: Please check the code that i have added now..

Answer (score 1):

For multipart upload as form data I was using Nativescript-background-Http 
Below is the sample implementation and it is working for me -

```
import { session, Session, Task } from "nativescript-background-http";
var session1 = session("image-upload");

uploadImage(fileUri, id) {

let imageName = this.extractImageName(fileUri);
let headers = new Headers();
headers.append("Authorization", Config.token);
headers.append("CenterId", Config.CenterId);
var options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
var request = {
  url: Config.putImage + id + "/upload",
  method: "POST",
  headers: {
    "Authorization": Config.token,
    "X-Center-Id": Config.XCenterId,
    "Content-Type": "application/octet-stream",
    "File-Name": imageName
  },

  description: "{ 'uploading': " + imageName + " }"
};
var params = [{ name: "image", filename: fileUri, mimeType: 'image/jpeg' }];
var task = session1.multipartUpload(params, request);
task.on("progress", logEvent);
task.on("error", logEvent);
task.on("complete", logEvent);

function logEvent(e) {
  console.log(".........................")
  console.log("currentBytes: " + e.currentBytes);
  console.log(".........................")
  console.log("totalBytes: " + e.totalBytes);
  console.log(".........................")
}

return task;
}

//Extract file Name
extractImageName(fileUri) {
var pattern = /[^/]*$/;
var imageName = fileUri.match(pattern);
return imageName;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Dlucidone.
My Server use PATCH method, body as formadata with key "profile_image" :"img_name.png".
My question is How to pass this body to above code?

Comment: use method: "PATCH" and "File-Name": img_name"and pass it to                -> this function uploadImage(fileUri, method_name, oranything)